Counterexamples to theorems about projective space when Noetherian hypotheses are removed
It is well known that over a Noetherian ring $A$, $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n_A, \mathscr{F})$ is a finitely generated $A$-module for every coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ of modules on $\mathbb{P}_A^n$ and $i \geq 0$.

Can anyone give me an explicit example of a coherent sheaf of modules $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$ with $A$ non-Noetherian and a $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n_A, \mathscr{F})$ which is not finitely generated over $A$? Preferrably, an example with $i = 0$.
As a related question, is it true that if we have a projective $A$-scheme $\operatorname{Proj}{S}$, where $S$ is a graded ring over a ring $A$ which is finitely generated in degree $1$ i.e. the degree $1$ elements of $S$ generate $S$ as an $A$-algebra, then the graded ring $\Gamma_\ast S = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma(\operatorname{Proj}{S}, \mathscr{O}(n))$ is also finitely generated in degree $1$? I have a feeling this is false in general even with Noetherian hypotheses but I can't give a counterexample.


Edit: I just realized that $\mathscr{F} = i_\ast \mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}{S}}$ is not coherent in my example (here, $i: \operatorname{Proj}{S} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is the obvious embedding), but at least it's finitely generated.
Let $A$ be a non-Noetherian ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$ which is not finitely generated. Define $S = A[x, y]/Ixy$. Then decomposing each $S_x$, $S_y$, and $S_{xy}$ by bidegree $x^ay^b$, we have $$S_x = \bigoplus_{\substack{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z^2 \\ b \geq 0}} A'_1, \quad S_y = \bigoplus_{\substack{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z^2 \\ a \geq 0}} A'_2, \quad S_{xy} = \bigoplus_{\substack{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z^2}}A/I,$$ where $$A_1' = \begin{cases} A &(a, b) = (0, 0), \\ A/I &b \ne 0, \end{cases} \quad A_2' = \begin{cases} A &(a, b) = (0, 0), \\ A/I &a \ne 0. \end{cases}$$
$H^0(\operatorname{Proj}{S}, \mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}{S}})$ is the kernel of the map $(S_x)_0 \times (S_y)_0 \to (S_{xy})_0$ defined by $(F, G) \mapsto F - G$, which by our explicit description of each ring is equal to pairs $(F, G) \in A^2$ with difference $F - G \in I$; as an $A$-module, this surjects via $(F, G) \mapsto F - G$ onto $I$, which is not finitely generated.

Edit 2: The second point has already been answered on MO.

Nice one ! Unless I'm mistaken, this only gives an example for $\operatorname{Proj}{S}$, which in this case is not of the form $\Bbb P_A^n =\operatorname{Proj}{A[x_0,...,x_n]}$.
